# Ram compatibility for ecc and precision

Tags: memory, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision 3610, 1 processor - 6 cores.

I have 16GB 2Rx4 PC4 - 2133P - RA0 - 10 Hynix RAM

Its my understanding that precisions accept ECC Ram, will this ram work?

If you need me to still provide motherboard info, I can

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dell Precision T3610 supports Registered ECC Memory type. So that spec should work.

Refer this link:

http://www.memorystock.com/memory/DellPrecisionWorkstationT3610.html